# do I really need swagger.json and swagger.yaml created in order to use Swagger for document a rest application

Tags: javascript, rest, jersey, swagger

I spent a whole day following Swagger guidance that basically inform that after added swagger dependency and deployed/started it I will get two files describing my rest services according to the use of Swagger annotations (eg. @Api). First of all, it is not clear if such two files are created after compile or during some specific phase (deployment to server, any specific maven phase or goal, or container start up). Well, this wasn't an issue at all if I was able to get that up and running (see my dificulties either [I can't get swagger.json neither swagger.yaml created althought I followed the guidance step by step](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41637944/i-cant-get-swagger-json-neither-swagger-yaml-created-althought-i-followed-the-g) or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41622018/i-cant-deploy-my-application-to-apache-tomcat-8-after-i-added-swagger-jersey-j).

I took a steep before by trying to run simple examples provided by others instead of following the official guidande and none  of them uses swagger.json and swagger.yaml.

Three examples running exactly as promissed by authors (expose documentations and features for testing):
1 - https://dzone.com/articles/swagger-make-developers-love
2 - https://sdngeeks.wordpress.com/2014/08/01/swagger-example-with-java-spring-apache-cxf-jackson/
3 - https://github.com/JakubStas/Spring4WithSwagger/blob/master/README.md

Nevertheless, none of them creates or seems to depends on such two files. So, my straight question is: do I really need such files for integrating my current Rest Services application to Swagger?

If not, as a complement point, what could be a common approach or way to integrate it without depending on such files? I noted all three examples have some files not described in the official Swagger guidance I was following (eg. swagger-ui.js, swagger-ui.min.js). I understand that such question may seem to large. So, to make it narrow, I am planning to base on same idea of such three examples, using backbone-min.js + swagger.js + underscore-min.js.

PS. by official guidance I mean https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-core/wiki/Swagger-Core-Jersey-1.X-Project-Setup-1.5#configure-and-initialize-swagger

Comment: Instead of asking a new question, you should improve [your previous question about this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41637944/1218980) to enhance the chances of getting answers.

Comment: Emile, they aren't same question at all. Did you note the previous is realated to deploy to TomCat and start the applicationw while this one is focused on swageer.json/yaml? On top of this, I clearly mentioned my doubt related to jersey compatibility there.